# Magento2.2 - File Upload Field from Order Comment Section

Tags: admin, orders, file-upload, magento-2.2.5

I have override following files for

- Displaying File Upload Fields -
  Magento_Sales::order/view/history.phtml
- To Process Comments
  -Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\AddComment
- To Display Block - Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\History

[image]

When i change `<input name="history[file]" type="file"` to `<input name="history[attachment]" type="text"` it works. Input text value can be received at controller level. Looks like file input is not processed in controller.

Comment: Have to create any database field to save this file path?

Comment: Yes, In controller Vendor\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\AddComment when i var_dump() post parameter then name of file field does display. In Short if input type is file then in controller input name does not process. If input type is text then this field is processed in controller.

Answer (score 0):

In Order, the comment is saving on Ajax request. So for this, It will not save file just using input type="file". You need to:

1. Modify Flow
   Remove entire flow from ajax based to form submit based and add enctype: multipart/form-data.

To Process Comments - Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\AddComment
print_r( $_FILES); // you will get all details about file for upload. And add custom changes to save file and comment.

2.With Current Flow ( Ajax Based )
As Magento2 Is rich with UI components feature. You can also use upload UI components feature.

```
<div class="upload-wrapper" data-bind="scope: 'uploader'">
    </div> <script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
       ".upload-wrapper": {
           "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
               "components": {
                   "uploader": {
                       "component": "Magento_Ui/js/form/element/file-uploader",
                       "template": "ui/form/element/uploader/uploader",
                       "allowedExtensions": "png",
                       "uploaderConfig": {
                            "url": "<?php echo $this->getUrl('sales/*/addComment', ['order_id' => $block->getOrder()->getId(),'type'=>'upload']) ?>"
                       }
                   }
               }
           }
       }
    } </script>
```

Do some changes to support file upload functionality in sales/*/addComment . Or Create Separate Controller for upload file functionality.

```
public function execute()
    {

    $error = false;

    // Do something with the file post var_dump($_FILES['files'])

    $result = ['error'=>$error,'success'=> ($error) ? false : true ];

    try {
            return $this->jsonResponse($result);
        } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
            return $this->jsonResponse($e->getMessage());
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->logger->critical($e);
            return $this->jsonResponse($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
```

3. Get File Path in response and append it in any hidden input to save file path in the comment.
4. And Submit Comment on addComment Action you need to save file path
   which is in the hidden field.

Hope this works for you.

Good Luck!