# File upload from order view page from admin

Tags: magento2, orders, sales-order, file-upload

```
<div class="admin__field-control">
        <input type="file" name="upload_custom_file" id="upload_custom_file" title="Upload Custom File" class="input-text" >
        <input type="text" name="uuuuu" id="uuuuu">
        <?= $block->getChildHtml('submit_button') ?>
    </div>
```

**Form in order view page.:**

[image]

**After submitting this not getting file response in controller.**

**Controller:**

```
        print_r($this->getRequest()->getPostValue());
        echo "<br>****<br>";
        print_r($this->getRequest()->getFiles());
        echo "<br>---<br>";
        print_r($this->getRequest()->getPost());
        echo "<br>****<br>";
        print_r($this->getRequest()->getParams());
 
 $yourInputFileName = 'upload_custom_file';
 echo "====".$file = $this->getRequest()->getFiles($yourInputFileName);
 print_r($file);
        die('--------');
```

**Response:**
[image]

[image]

Comment: can you please verify in the form enctype

please refer this one - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/239761/magento2-2-file-upload-field-from-order-comment-section

Answer (score 0):

please `data-form-part="order_form_name"` attribute  in the input so that i can be part of the specfic form